# Checking if a username exists within a sqlite database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Pretty generic question, but none of the other solutions seemed to work for me.

This is what I have, and at the moment it always returns that the Username doesn't exist. I want the code to go through all the data and check if an input (x) can be found in the table. Thanks.

x = an input from the user
c = conn.cursor()

```
def read_from_db():
   c.execute("SELECT user FROM stuffToPlot ") 
   if x in c.fetchall():
      print('Username already exists')
   if x not in c.fetchall():
      print("Username doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Ignore the three ``` at the end, they are a mistake.

Comment: We don't know anything about your database layout, but it seems like you should have a `WHERE` clause that indicates the user name. Then it will either find it returning a value or not, returning None. Right now it looks like you are selecting the entire table and manually scanning it, which kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: This code is not even valid Python. What is `c`? What is `x`? What is `row`?

Comment: x = an input from the user asking for their username
c = conn.cursor() 
sorry about row, it's meant to say c.fetchall():

Answer (score 0):

This seems like pretty standard SQL: just parametrize your query with the username,

```py
c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM stuffToPlot where user = %s", [x])
```

this will return a row for each user matching `x`. Which is likely either 0 or 1 row (if you can have multiple `stuffToPlot` with the same `user` you could always add a `limit 1` to the query). You can then check `cr.rowcount` to see if you would have results without even bothering to fetch them: you just want to see if there's a match:

```py
if c.rowcount:
    print('Username already exists')
else:
    print("Username doesn't exist")
```

Alternatively, you could use [`EXISTS`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#exists_op) and fetch one row telling you whether there's any matching row, that's what the operator is for and it'd probably be more efficient:

```py
c.execute('select exists(select 1 from stuffToPlot where user = %s)', [x])
[exists] = cr.fetchone() # fetch and unpack the only row our query returns
if exists:
    print('Username already exists')
else:
    print("Username doesn't exist")
```

There are a bunch of issues with your Python though.

1. SQL queries always return *rows*, meaning `fetchall` is always a list of tuples (even when you get a single value), meaning you'll never find a string in there
2. as its name indicates, `fetchall` *fetches* all rows, meaning the second `fetchall` will always return an empty list (there's nothing left to fetch)
3. `if a: ... else: ...` is much better than `if a: ... if not a: ...`
4. as hinted in my proposition, it's generally a better idea to filter your data in the database (using proper parameterizing) than retrieving the entirety of the database then filtering in Python

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's valid for all librairies but it seems than fetchall() method for sqllite return a tuple of tuples.

*The fetchall() method gets all records. It returns a result set. Technically, it is a tuple of tuples. Each of the inner tuples represent a row in the table.*

So you can try:

```
for query_result in c.fetchall() :
    if x in query_result:
        print('Username already exists') 
    else:
        print("Username doesn't exist" )
```